# AWS SDK S3 ListObjectsV2 gives NullReferenceException in Photon Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, photon

I'm running AWS SDK from Photon Server application and trying to query the contents of S3 bucket using the AmazonS3Client.ListObjectsV2() method based on the example from AWS site. Using the same code in another application works just fine, but in the Photon Server application it outputs the following error message to Photon logs

```
2016-10-12 15:19:52,614 [11] ERROR Photon.SocketServer.ApplicationBase [(null)] - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
at System.Configuration.UriSectionReader.GetSectionData()
at System.Configuration.UriSectionInternal.LoadUsingCustomParser(String appConfigFilePath)
at System.Configuration.UriSectionInternal.GetSection()
at System.Uri.InitializeUriConfig()
at System.Uri.InitializeUri(ParsingError err, UriKind uriKind, UriFormatException& e)
at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.ComposeUrl(IRequest iRequest)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.CreateWebRequest(IRequestContext requestContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpHandler`1.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RedirectHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Unmarshaller.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ResponseHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RetryHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.S3.Internal.AmazonS3ExceptionHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorCallbackHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.MetricsHandler.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.RuntimePipeline.InvokeSync(IExecutionContext executionContext)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient.Invoke[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, IMarshaller`2 marshaller, ResponseUnmarshaller unmarshaller)
at Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client.ListObjectsV2(ListObjectsV2Request request)
at AWSConnector.AWSConnector.ListSubfolders(String prefix)
at InstanceManager.Handlers.InstanceManagerUpdateInstancesHandler.OnHandleMessage(IMessage message, PhotonServerPeer serverPeer)
at Boson.Photon.Server.PhotonServerHandlerList.HandleMessage(IMessage message, PhotonServerPeer peer)
at Boson.Photon.Server.PhotonServerPeer.OnOperationRequest(OperationRequest operationRequest, SendParameters sendParameters)
at Photon.SocketServer.ServerToServer.ServerPeerBase.OnReceiveInternal(Byte[] data, SendParameters sendParameters, Int32 rtt, Int32 rttVariance, Int32 numFailures)
at Photon.SocketServer.PeerBase.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Photon.SocketServer.IManagedPeer.Application_OnReceive>b__5()
at ExitGames.Concurrency.Core.DefaultExecutor.Execute(Action toExecute)
at ExitGames.Concurrency.Core.DefaultExecutor.Execute(List`1 toExecute)
at ExitGames.Concurrency.Fibers.PoolFiber.Flush(Object )
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

I'm afraid this might have something to do with the way threading is handled in Photon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe that neither Photon, nor AWS are not involved here. 
The "System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)" method throws NREs in other scenarios. It appears to coincide with of of the latest security fixes deployed by Microsoft.

For example, this is a stack trace I'm struggling with right now:

```
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.CheckIllegalCharacters(String[] str, Boolean onlyCheckExtras)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
at System.Web.InternalSecurityPermissions.PathDiscovery(String path)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.get_CodegenDir()
```

It appears that .NET 4.6.2 is the culprit here.

Compare the [FileIOPermission in 4.6.2](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/1acafe20a789a55daa17aac6bb47d1b0ec04519f/mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs#L550) and [FileIOPermission in 4.6.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/e458f8df6ded689323d4bd1a2a725ad32668aaec/mscorlib/system/security/permissions/fileiopermission.cs#L543) -- they obviously changed the illegal path checks, so the [contract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h05w5es7(v=vs.110).aspx) of the FileIOPermission constructor throwing ArgumentException on invalid path is broken.

Comment: Raised an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/12584) with the .NET team.

Comment: Weirdly enough i'm using the same AWSConnector dll (.NET 4.5.2) I created in both the Photon application and console application (both .NET 4.5.2). Solved my problem when starting the console application from the photon application instead of using the dll from photon code directly.

Comment: I believe that the build target FW doesn't actually matter here, it's the runtime version on the target machine.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thanks for clearing that up, @onyXMaster